# What is the rationale for calling "The Interview" racist?

Tags: reception, the-interview

I've seen some people calling "The Interview" racist, including on Twitter. What is their rationale for that claim?

Comment: I believe this question is probably off topic, so will just leave a comment. I'll caveat this with the statement I haven't seen the movie (nor even snippets of it), but the people who are calling the movie *racist* really don't know what the term racist means. Like so many others, they throw the term out there not having a clue, or believing by calling others racist, they themselves cannot be. JMHO, though.

Comment: Could you post a link to specific claims. At present it's not clear what exactly is being claimed. Some context might be useful.

Comment: After doing an (albeit short and) quick Google Search for "the interview" movie racist, I haven't actually found any hits. Maybe I worded my search incorrectly. Could you point to "some people" so we can see the racism claims against the movie?

Comment: You are asking us to explain the rationale behind comments of random people on twitter, but fail to even provide an example of such a comment. And all that about a movie that isn't even released. Not sure how this could be ever answered reasonably.

Comment: Brave heroic white guys succeed making a silly Asian guy cry, and then proceed to destroy him with a tank while other Asian men fail to do anything they're supposed to, but instead die. Oh, the unattractive white guy gets the Asian girl. (As always Asian women portrayed as simple and submissive beauties.) So yeah, a racist Hollywood movie.

Answer (score 4):

The film has been accused of being racist because it uses Racism as part of its arsenal of gags: but, what is key here, is that the characters using this racism are (whilst protagonists) not supposed to be *likable.*

What is key here is that we are laughing at them because of their racism, **not along with their racism.**

The film does not in any way defend their casual racism, or support it as the position of the film makers. As the Guardian [has pointed out](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/dec/19/the-interview-film-guide-sony-hack), the point of the film is to ridicule the two characters for being if not racist, at least ignorant...

> Putting two American dinguses in North Korea is rich source material
>   for racial stereotyping, but the jokes are, by and large, self-aware;
>   the laughs at the expense of the dumb racist. One must tip the hat to
>   Rogen for finding a way to craft a “me so solly” joke that isn’t
>   offensive.